# apt-get update error source/source/Sources Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates

I am faced with an an annoying error with `apt-get update` which is giving me the annoying red triangle telling me my `sources.list` is wrong or malformed. I've checked my sources file over an over and I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with it. Here's screenshot of what I'm getting

[image]

I've tried doing

```
    sudo apt-get clean all
```

but this didn't do anything to fix it. I did even try just simply deleting the sources.list file and just do

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

to just create a new sources.list, but I'm then again presented with the same error over and it's getting annoying having that stupid recurring red triangle in the top of my menu bar.

Why do I have a deprecated or non-working deb/deb-src URL for `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release` that it can't even grab properly?

Does Canonical even provide software for 13.04 at all or should I just have to disable it completely?

Comment: It would be more useful to provide a pastebin or similar of the whole command output and your source list instead of a window capture.

Answer (score 3):

Line 51 in your `sources.list` is wrong.

```
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner source
```

Replace it with

```
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner universe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)..(coz I don't think that deleting it will solve your problem)

This will **create a complete new sources.list for you** After providing proper information
replace the new sources.list with your current! and you are done!

This link helped me some time ago to solve my problem with sources.list

Hope this helps!

Comment: why does that linked site omit Raring?  It has 12.04 but no 13.04!